# Intersection of connected components in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: gn.general-topology, real-analysis

Let $n$ be a positive integer and let $K\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be compact. Pick $x^* \in \mathbb{R}^n\setminus K$.

Let $E$ be the connected component of $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus K$ that contains $x^*$. Let ${\cal C}$ be the collection of connected components of $K$. For each $C\in {\cal C}$ let $E_C$ be the connected component of $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus C$ that contains $x^*$.

Is it true that $E=\bigcap\{E_C: C\in{\cal C}\}$?

Comment: Note that this statement is false if one replaces "connected component" by "path-connected component".

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner isn't for open subsets of locally path-connected space all notions related to connectivity and path-connectivity coincide?

Comment: @erz: yes, but the question includes connected components of the compact set $K$.

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner oh yes, of course, sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to this problem is Yes.

Indeed, the inclusion $E\subset \bigcap_{C\in\mathcal C}E_C$ is trivial, so it remains to prove that for any point $x\in\mathbb R^n\setminus E$ there exists a connected component $C\in\mathcal C$ of $K$ such that $x\notin E_C$. By Zorn's Lemma, the compact set $K$ contains a minimal closed subset $S\subset K$ such that the points $x^*$ and $x$ belong to distinct components of $X\setminus S$. 
Such a minimal compact set $S$ is called an *irreducible barrier* between $x$ and $x^*$. The Claim below implies that the irreducible barrier $S$ is connected. Then for the connected component $C$ of $K$ containing the irreducible barrier $S$ we get $x\notin E_C$.

**Claim.** *The irreducible barrier $S$ is connected*.

*Proof.* The proof involves some tools of algebraic topology. I do not know if there is a more elementary proof. Assuming that $S$ is disconnected, we can write $S$ as the disjoint union $A\cup B$ of two non-empty compact sets. Since $S$ is a minimal barrier between $x$ and $x^*$ the points $x,x^*$ can be linked by a path in $\mathbb R^n\setminus A$ and  $\mathbb R^n\setminus B$. Since $x,x^*$ belong to different connected components, the 0-dimensional singular cycle $\alpha=x-x^*$  detemines a non-zero-element in the homology group $H_0(\mathbb R^n\setminus S)$.
Now observe that $(\mathbb R^n\setminus A)\cup(\mathbb R^n\setminus B)=\mathbb R^n\setminus(A\cap B)=\mathbb R^n$ and write the exact [Mayer-Vietoris sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mayer%E2%80%93Vietoris_sequence) 
$$H_0(\mathbb R^n)\to H_0(\mathbb R^n\setminus S)\to H_0(\mathbb R^n\setminus A)\oplus H_0(\mathbb R^n\setminus B).$$ By the minimality of $S$, the image of the singular cycle $\alpha$ in $H_0(\mathbb R^n\setminus A)\oplus H_0(\mathbb R^n\setminus B)$ is trivial. Now the exactness of the Mayer-Vietros sequence implies that $\alpha$ is zero in $H_0(\mathbb R^n\setminus S)$, which is a desired contradiction.

Comment: Wow - amazing, thanks Taras!! This question has been open on MO for almost 3 years. I didn't get a handle on it myself at all. Thanks again!

Comment: @DominicvanderZypen I noticed that the highest probability to get an answer is in several days after posing the problem. Concerning this your question, I think we have not so much good continuum theorists here in mathoverflow (irreducible barriers should be well-known to specialists, I hope). The same concerns general topology, it turns out that this field is far from being overcrowded and the number of topologists seems to decrease in time, unfortunately.

Comment: @DominicvanderZypen Dominic, I am afraid that you have not noticed that I wrote anwers to other two problems posed by you: (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/289740/maximal-elements-in-the-partially-ordered-set-of-image-spaces) and (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/223909/minimal-hausdorff-topologies-compatible-with-a-bunch-of-functions). The last problem was really difficult!

Comment: Oh - I haven't noticed, sorry for my mistake @TarasBanakh! Will have time to read your answers later this afternoon