# On minimality of semitopological and quasitopological groups

Tags: gn.general-topology, topological-groups

The phenomemnon of minimality is [well-studied](http://u.cs.biu.ac.il/~megereli/DMsurveyFinal.pdf) in the realm of topological groups.

Let us recall that a topological group $X$ is *minimal* if each bijecive continuous homomorphism $h:X\to Y$ to a topological group $Y$ is a topological isomorphism.

I am interested if the notion of minimality was studied in the realm of semi-topological or quasi-topological groups.

A *semi-topological group* is a group $G$ endowed with a Hausdorff topology making the group operation $G\times G\to G$, $(x,y)\mapsto xy$, separately continuous.

A semitopological group is called a *quasi-topological group* if the operation of inversion $G\to G$, $x\mapsto x^{-1}$, is continuous.

Let us define a semi-topological group $X$ to be *semi-minimal* if each continuous bijective homomorphism $h:X\to Y$ to a  semitopological group $Y$ is a topological isomorphism.

By analogy we can define a quasi-topological group $X$ to be *quasi-minimal* if each continuous bijective homomorphism $h:X\to Y$ to a quasi-topological group $Y$ is a topological isomorphism.

It is clear that each semi-minimal quasi-topological group is quasi-minimal and each quasi-minimal topological group is minimal.

It can be shown that each compact Hausdorff semitopological group is semi-minimal (topological group).

**Problem 1.** Is each semi-minimal semi-topological group compact?

**Problem 2.** Is each quasi-minimal quasi-topological group compact?

I even cannot prove or disprove the following

**Conjecture.** No countable Boolean semi-topological group is semi-minimal.

**Remark.** By the answer to [this MO problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/223909/minimal-hausdorff-topologies-compatible-with-a-bunch-of-functions), for some submonoid $M$ of the monoid $\omega^\omega$ of self-maps of a countable set $X$ there is no minimal Hausdorff topology on $\omega$ in which all self-maps $f\in M$ are continuous. At the moment this is the unique (known to me) example of an algebraic systems with unary operations, admitting no minimal Hausdorff topology.